# Temporary way to convert base urls in HTML

Tags: html, http, apache2

Right now I have a website with all the `href` and `src` point to `/some/url`. There's always a slash in the beginning.

I'm currently testing the site using a subdirectory on the server, which has the address of `http://somedomain.com/subdirectory/` (production would be `http://somedomain.com`)

Is there anyway to temporarily convert the `/some/url` from `http://somedomain.com/some/url` to `http://somedomain.com/subdirectory/some/url` without actually changing each of the `href` and `src` properties. From what I can make out of the `base` tag, it doesn't work like that. Also changing the `RewriteBase` from `/` to `/subdirectory` also doesn't work (Not too familiar with mod_rewrite, maybe someone can fill me in on that)

Comment: If you have access to apache and domain configuration, I would suggest creating new virtual server (ie. `somedirectory.somedomain.com`) with `DocumentRoot` pointing to your `somedirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .htaccess file in **somedomain.com** dir U can put:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://somedomain.com/subdirectory/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) might be able to do this. From the documentation:

> mod_proxy_html is an output filter to
>   rewrite HTML links in a proxy
>   situation, to ensure that links work
>   for users outside the proxy. It serves
>   the same purpose as Apache's
>   `ProxyPassReverse` directive does for
>   HTTP headers, and is an essential
>   component of a reverse proxy.
>
> For example, if a company has an
>   application server at
>   `appserver.example.com` that is only
>   visible from within the company's
>   internal network, and a public
>   webserver `www.example.com`, they may
>   wish to provide a gateway to the
>   application server at
>   `http://www.example.com/appserver/`.
>   When the application server links to
>   itself, those links need to be
>   rewritten to work through the gateway.
>   mod_proxy_html serves to rewrite `<a
>   href="http://appserver.example.com/foo/bar.html">foobar</a>`
>   to foobar
>   making it accessible from outside.